# Data Modeling for special e-commerce Site in Aerospike

Tags: node.js, aerospike

Hello I have just started using Aerospike so I need some details what will be the good data model for my e-commerce platform, I am not able to design a data model for this in Aerospike which can work perfectly.

Here are some basic requirements for my e-commerce platform:

1.>User Set(For login & register an basic information of user)

2.>Product Set (For storing product info like name and image and options and color options etc)

3.>Order Set ( To track record of the user order )

The complex requirement for the special Set required for database is as follows:

1.For each product that a user will buy a Share Code will be generated which a user can share with his/her friends and family to get benefits for future.

2.The user who buys a product with somebody’s Share code, then the details that this user bought the “xyz” product must be transferred to the owner of the share code and also a Share code for this user will also be generate which he/she can share with his/her friend.

3.And also the user must be able to know how many persons shared his/her code an also the user’s who buys a product from the share code of the 1st level user’s Share Code.

4. So I want to keep record of the users 2 level below the current user.

Comment: Hi, please be sure to check out the official documentation about how to perform common database modeling with Aerospike: http://www.aerospike.com/datamodeling/modeling-data-aerospike/ . Aerospike also offers a data modeling course (with both virtual and classroom sessions) if you need more info: http://bit.ly/_AS301

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to model a Multi-Level-Marketing order management system.

User and Product are straight forward. Records TTL = live for ever, never delete for all sets. user_info, product_info may be updated.

For simplicity, each product purchase is just one product_id. 
By PK I mean the primary key of the record.

```
User Set: {PK:user_id, user_info:{.....}}
Product Set: {PK:product_id, product_info:{.....}}
Order Set: {
PK: order_id, 
order_details:{buyer:user_id, 
item:product_id, qty:..., 
share_code: "order_id:xyz", 
parent_code:"parent_order_id:abc" }, 
level1_orders:[List of order_ids], 
level2_orders:[List of order_ids]
}
```

The share_code is composite string comprising the order_id:some_code.
For first set of orders (level 0 orders) parent_code may be zero.

Consider order_id = 213, share code: "213:abc", parent_code:"112:pqr"

If any user purchases using share code "213:abc", and this level 1 purchase order_id is 310, make entry in Order set for {PK:310, ... share_code:"310:cde", parent_code:"213:abc", ....} then update order_id=213 - to its level1_orders list, append 310 order_id.If order 213 has a parent_code, in this case it is "112:pqr" also update order_id 112 in its Level2 order lists by appending this order_id, 310 to it.

Now you have all the info you need for your model.

Note: This is a multi-record update model. Be mindful of potential inconsistencies if client fails midway or other bad things happen. There are advanced techniques to address that situation.

However, this may be a good starting point for you. Let me know if this was helpful. If it is different than what you wanted (your part 3 was not very clear to me), you may have to modify the model but the technique highlighted may be helpful.