# What is the best schema design for simple feed system? -Aerospike

Tags: node.js, aerospike

I am trying to develop an e-commerce application and I am trying to use the concept of feeds to be used in my app. Whenever a user buys something , a feed like thing will be generated for it which can be seen by the other users in two ways:

1. If the user is following  the person who bought the product he/she can see the feed.(This is a customised feed in which the buyer tells to share only with the persons who is following him/her)
2. The generated feed will be shown/available to all the users who are using the app.(In this case the buyer must select the option to share with everyone option)

This is my use case, I am using the following technology to build the Backend for this:

1. NodeJs
2. Aerospike

My use case includes a social network system sort of thing. What is the best way to solve this?

I have gone through [Twitter Application Aerospike](https://github.com/aerospike/tweetaspike) but there is no pagination in this and also I am afraid that this schema might fail If I try to scale.

Comment: Did you look at the similar modeling question you asked last month? I posted a response. Is this the same thing?

Comment: Here is that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474808/data-modeling-for-special-e-commerce-site-in-aerospike

Comment: No the previous question is different as in that I am trying to just attach the list of down level orders , but in here I want a feed type structure in which a user can follow other user just like in Instagram and that user can see the products that the users buy whom he/she follows. So in here if a user say "A" is following 100 persons then "A" can see the feeds of the Order(as a post) that any of the persons  "A" follows.